# Simple input - output converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, type-conversion

I'm currently trying yo make a simple program that will take the user's input and spit out the same thing but with different letters/characters based on a simple conversion table.

Ex: Lets say the following are the conversions; on the left side you have the user's input and on the right you have the programs output.

```
A=AB
B=BC
C=CD
D=DE
etc...
```

I want to make the program take a sentence or phrase and spit out the converted version:

Ex: This is what I want as the end product.

```
Input = Hello there
Output = HIEFLMLMOP TUHIEFRSEF
```

I only have little experience with Python I must admit. It has been a little over 4 years since I had a programming class in high school and we learned an older version before 3.0 so a few things seem to be new/different. Any help is much appreciated!

Edit:

```
import sys

'a' == "AB"
'b' == "BC"
'c' == "CD"
'd' == "DE"
'e' == "EF"
'f' == "FG"
'g' == "GH"
'h' == "HI"
'i' == "IJ"
'j' == "JK"
'k' == "KL"
'l' == "LM"
'm' == "MN"
'n' == "NO"
'o' == "OP"
'p' == "PQ"
'q' == "QR"
'r' == "RS"
's' == "ST"
't' == "TU"
'u' == "UV"
'v' == "VW"
'w' == "WX"
'x' == "XY"
'y' == "YZ"
'z' == "ZA"

usrinpt = input('Enter what you would like to encode:');
print("Generated Product:");
if input(usrinpt) == a:
    print ("AB")
def main():
    input("Press enter and exit")
```

Edit 2:

Tried out what @wwii suggested but just don't seem to know how I'd have the program spit-out the conversion.

```
import sys

translate = {"A": 'AB', "B": 'BC', "C": 2, "D": 3, "E": 4, "F": 5, "G": 6, "H": 7, "I": 8, "J": 9, "K": 10, "L": 11, "M": 12, "N": 13, "O": 14, "P": 15, "Q": 16, "R": 17, "S": 18, "T": 19, "U": 20, "V": 21, "W": 22, "X": 23, "Y": 24, "Z": 25, " ": 26}

conversion = input("What would you like cypher?: ").upper()
print("Here is the output: "conversion)
```

Edit 3: 
Found some code that seems to be really close to what I'm looking for. Just having troubles getting it to read my translations.

```
key = 0

translate = {'a':'AB' , 'b':'BC'}
#going to add more to the translate list once I get those letters working

def wub():
    def choice():
        choice = input("Do you wish to Encrypt of Decrypt?")
        choice = choice.lower()
        if choice == "e" or "encrypt":
            return choice
        elif choice == "d" or "decrypt":
            return choice
        else:
            print("Invalid response, please try again.")
            choice()

    def message():
        user = input("Enter your message: ")
        return user

    def waffle(choice, message, key):
        translated = ""
        if choice == "e" or "encrypt":
            for character in message:
                num = ord(character)
                num += key
                translated += chr(num)

                derek = open('Encrypted.txt', 'w')
                derek.write(translated)
            derek.close()
            return translated
        else:
            for character in message:
                num = ord(character)
                num -= key
                translated += chr(num)
            return translated

    choice = choice() #Runs function for encrypt/decrypt selection. Saves choice made.
    message = message() #Run function for user to enter message. Saves message.
    final = waffle(choice, message, key) #Runs function to translate message, using the choice, message and key variables)
    print("\n Operation complete!")
    print(final)

wub(
```

)

Comment: Well, you must have tried something.... do you have some code that doesn't work? Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, *Z* translates to *ZA*?

Comment: Expected output is not very clear to me. Also, I am sure you can do what you wish to do in the older version as well. Show what you have tried and if you are stuck somewhere somebody will help you out

Comment: a good place to start would be making a function that takes in a string made of a single character, and uses `ord` and `chr` functions and the `string.upper()` method all together to return a string that the character should be replaced with.

Comment: @mad_  the character x maps to the characters X,X+1 But it is unclear what z/Z should map to...

Comment: I think Z should map to A. See how the [Caesar_cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) handles those cases.

Comment: :D `"".join([item + (chr(ord(item) + 1) if item >= "A" and item < "Z" else "A" if item == "Z" else "") for item in text.upper()])`

Comment: @t.m.adam: *Caesar* maps each chars to another **one**, which is not the case here.

Comment: @CristiFati In terms of code I've tried, I couldn't get it to work properly but I will still post it in an edit real quick.

Comment: @CristiFati Sure, however it's also a substitution cipher, and it could help the OP understand how to handle edge letters (just the z in this case).

Comment: Based on the added code, I'd recommend a *Python* tutorial.

Comment: The comparisons at the beginning of your code are not used so would be returns false to stdout you need to use the syntax string.replace("old","new"). you would also have to check for unreplaced characters

Comment: Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to map characters to their *encodings* - `translate = {'a':'AB', 'b':'BC', ...}`

Comment: @t.m.adam Well I had looked into just converting a ceasar cipher into what I want, but they require a key which jumbles the letters around based on the number the user inputs as the key.

Comment: @BobQKazoo You can use a variation of the Caesar cipher where the key is always 1. Example: `l + string.ascii_uppercase[(string.ascii_uppercase.index(l) + 1) % 26]`. Or you could use a dictionary as wwii suggested.

Comment: Posted another update. Now the reason why I don't want to use a Key of 1 is because I'm not planning to make it as simple as A = AB etc, I'm going to use different letter combinations; Just used that example for ease of troubleshooting.

Comment: @BobQKazoo: Did you try the code snipped that I placed in a previous comment? Note that it assumes that the input string is stored in a variable called `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this or similar within a function, you may be able to avoid the output str all together. If you wish to handle lowercase's as well check the chr() integer value and if above 96, subtract 32:

```
def convert(inputString):
    outputString = ""
    for letter in inputString:
        if ord(letter) >= 65 and ord(letter) < 86:
            outputString += letter + chr((ord(letter) + 1))
        elif ord(letter) >= 97 and ord(letter) < 122:
            outputString += chr(ord(letter) - 32) + chr(ord(letter) - 31)
        elif letter == 'z' or letter == 'Z':
            outputString += "ZA"
        else:
            outputString += letter
    return outputString

wordToConvert = "ABC abc"

print(convert( wordToConvert))

wordToConvert = "Hello there"

print(convert( wordToConvert))
```

Output:

```
ABBCCD ABBCCD
HIEFLMLMOP TUHIEFRSEF
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr

https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-in-the-ASCII-values-of-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters

Comment: This does indeed work now. I implemented the full function, the previous post was intended as a guide hence "try this or similar". Appreciate the detailed feedback.